# form não envia arquivo para upload

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um form cujo ele preciso fazer upload para um ftp.

Quando eu coloco da forma a baixo não carrega arquivo.

```
<form id="frmEnviar" name="frmEnviar" data-ajax="false" method="post" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">

</form>
```

Já da forma abaixo carrega arquivo.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Inserir", "ProtocoloLatam", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{


}
```

Porque da primeira forma não funciona?

Comment: Adicione `action="arquivo.ext"` para ver se resolve, informando o arquivo que irá receber a solicitação.

Comment: Amigo, tem o method="post" no form, mas o que é esse action?

Comment: Desculpe Gabriel, não percebi que tinha o method. Porém esse "action" informa a página que irá receber os dados do formulário.

Comment: Action é o destino para onde o form deverá apontar, no seu caso na segunda opção ele está enviando para "/ProtocoloLatam/Inserir", já no que você construiu, faltou direcionar o post para algum lugar declarando a action... logo ele vai tentar postar para sua própria rota

Comment: Pois bem, esse "ProtocoloLatam/Inserir" é enviado via uma requisição ajax, via get

Comment: Como posso fazer esse upload

Comment: Bom, aí a pergunta não é nem sobre c# ou Asp.Net e sim sobre javascript

Comment: Como assim? O arquivo tem que ser enviado via javascript tb?

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com//questions/9704/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80878/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-leandro-angelo).

Comment: Funcionaria com o get ou só com post?